# How make method run only once

Tags: java, android, android-studio, methods

I have a button which starts `copy` method and goes to background and `copiedText`method which pastes the copied text into a list adapter. 
When i open my application and press `copy` button then its copying same text again. It is getting increased by the number of times i press `copy` button.
How to stop it from entering multiple times. i need that method to run only once.

```
     private void copy() {
       String name = EditTxt.getText().toString();
        copiedText();

        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);

}

public void copiedText() {
    //copy text from clipboard to adapter
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


    ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mPrimaryChangeListener =
            new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

                    clipText = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

                    adapter.add(clipText);
                    //refresh
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text is copied                   to MultiCopy flot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            };
    clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mPrimaryChangeListener);
}
```

Comment: You need to save a button state variable based on your use case. Save whether the button should be enabled/disabled in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Use SharedPreference to control the execution of your copeidText() method...

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of boolean variable to keep track of whether copying is allowed or not.
Check if it is true before copying.
make it false when you start copying.
Then once job is done make it true again.

check this code:

```
boolean isCopyAllowed=true;

 private void copy() {
    if(isCopyAllowed){
        isCopyAllowed=false;
        String name = EditTxt.getText().toString();
        copiedText();

        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
     }
}

public void copiedText() {
    //copy text from clipboard to adapter
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


    ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mPrimaryChangeListener =
            new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

                    clipText = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

                    adapter.add(clipText);
                    //refresh
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text is copied                   to MultiCopy flot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            };
    clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mPrimaryChangeListener);
    isCopyAllowed=true;
}
```